# Get list of documents and pages downloaded by user

Tags: usage-counters, reports

Is there any way to get a list of documents and pages within a MOSS 2007 site collection downloaded by a user over, say, the last seven days?

(without using a log file analyser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to look into auditing. Here's something to get you started: http://admincompanion.mindsharp.com/BillBlog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=18

Answer (score 0):

MOSS comes with some basic audit reports. Have a look at [this resource on Office Online](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA101000051033.aspx) for more details.

Alternatively, have a look at our [SharePoint Audit Suite](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/SharePoint-Audit/summary.aspx). It is cheap and does exactly what you are after.

I worked on the product so I am obviously biased :-)

Comment: Try to keep the product plugs to a minimum here at SPOverflow. I know your input is always great, so just a friendly warning. ;+)

Comment: Will do Marc. It is always a fine line.